# DOM manupulation: how to remove an element from list of json data dymically in javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

i want to delete a row by clicking delete button which return an id from JSON data, i have created all the elements in DOM. i am trying to add delete function but it only delete the JSON data it does not delete the DOM. I have tried the Object oriented way but i didn't know how to used them. it will be extremely helpful if there is any suggestion.

```js
let names = {
  nameList: [{
      userId: 1,
      name: "abc",
      age: "25",
    },
    {
      userId: 2,
      name: "def",
      age: "23",
    },
    {
      userId: 3,
      name: "ghi",
      age: "18",
    },
    {
      userId: 4,
      name: "jkl",
      age: "19",
    },
  ],
  find: function() {
    console.log("Find function");
  },
  add: function() {
    return this.nameList[1];
  },
  delete: function() {
    console.log("Delete function");
  },
};



const createEle = (data, idx) => {
  let main = document.createElement("div");
  let container = document.getElementById("container");
  let title = document.createElement('div');
  let age = document.createElement('div');
  let remove = document.createElement('div');
  let update = document.createElement('div');
  main.className = "main";
  title.className = "title";
  age.className = "age";
  remove.className = "delete";
  update.className = "update";

  container.appendChild(main);
  main.appendChild(title);
  main.appendChild(age);
  main.appendChild(update);
  main.appendChild(remove);

  remove.addEventListener("click", deleteEle.bind(event, idx));

  title.append(data.name);
  age.append(data.age);
  update.append("Edit");
  remove.append("Delete");

}

const displayData = () => {
  names.nameList.map(data => {
    createEle(data, data.userId);

  });
}

const deleteEle = (idx) => {
  names.nameList.splice(idx - 1, 1)
  console.log("deleted", idx, names.nameList);
}



displayData();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Todo list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" value="" class="input">
    <button class="find">Find</button>
    <button class="add">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="container"></div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely remove the data from DOM when you delete it from the list. I would suggest a simple approach where you have to assign an id to all the main div that you create dynamically. And later when the deleteEle function is called you remove that from DOM.

Add following line to createEle function of yours

```
const createEle = (data, idx) => {
*** rest code***
  let remove = document.createElement('div');
  let update = document.createElement('div');
  main.id =idx; //NEW LINE ADDED
  main.className = "main";
*** rest code***
}
```

Update your deleteEle as follows

```
const deleteEle = (idx) => {
  names.nameList.splice(idx - 1, 1)
  console.log("deleted", idx, names.nameList);
  document.getElementById(idx).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete all the html from inside `.container` and render everything again.

---

Edit: also, be careful trying to delete by the item's `index` in the array when you are in fact passing the `userId` to the `deleteEle` function.

You probably want to first find the `index` of the item that has the matching `userId`, then use this found `index` to remove the item from the array.

```js
let nameList = [{
    userId: 1,
    name: "abc",
    age: "25",
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    name: "def",
    age: "23",
  },
  {
    userId: 3,
    name: "ghi",
    age: "18",
  },
  {
    userId: 4,
    name: "jkl",
    age: "19",
  },
];

let container = document.getElementById("container");


const createEle = (data, userId) => {
  let main = document.createElement("div");
  let title = document.createElement('div');
  let age = document.createElement('div');
  let remove = document.createElement('button');

  main.className = "main";
  title.className = "title";
  age.className = "age";
  remove.className = "delete";

  main.appendChild(title);
  main.appendChild(age);
  main.appendChild(remove);

  remove.addEventListener("click", deleteEle.bind(event, userId));

  title.append(data.name);
  age.append(data.age);
  remove.append("Delete");

  container.appendChild(main);
}

const displayData = () => {
  nameList.map(data => {
    createEle(data, data.userId);
  });
}

const deleteEle = (userId) => {
  const indexToDelete = nameList.findIndex(item => item.userId === userId)
  if (indexToDelete !== -1) {
    nameList.splice(indexToDelete, 1)
  }


  container.innerHTML = "";
  displayData();
}



displayData();
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
```

Comment: this works but it didn't delete the last second element.

Comment: @Nandakumarsingh i have updated my answer. There was a flaw in your `deleteEle` function.

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute ID with the div and you can use it when you want to delete data from DOM

```
const createEle = (data, idx) => {
   let main = document.createElement("div");
   let id = document.createAttribute("id");
   let container = document.getElementById("container");
   let title = document.createElement('div');
   let age = document.createElement('div');
   let remove = document.createElement('div');
   let update = document.createElement('div');
   main.className = "main";
   main.id=data.userId;
   title.className = "title";
   age.className = "age";
   remove.className = "delete";
   update.className = "update";

   container.appendChild(main);
   main.appendChild(title);
   main.appendChild(age);
   main.appendChild(update);
   main.appendChild(remove);

   remove.addEventListener("click", deleteEle.bind(event, idx));

   title.append(data.name);
   age.append(data.age);
   update.append("Edit");
   remove.append("Delete");
 }

const deleteEle = (idx) => {
  let id =document.getElementById(idx);
  console.log("deleting", id);
  id.remove();
  names.nameList.splice(idx - 1, 1)
  console.log("deleted", id, names.nameList);
```

}